# How to get cursor out of an input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I use an input field as a "shield" or "fake input" for the file input field.

There is no way for the user to click in it as i put a "block" div above it.

However when I open up the jQuery dialog holding the fake input the cursor is placed in the input.

How can I keep this from happening.

It seems to be some default behavior of the browse to move the cursor to this place.

For some reason this is not reproducible in the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/36t3G/2/

```
function fooboo (moo){
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the input disabled or readonly

```
 <input name="name" type="text" readonly>
 <input name="name" type="text" disabled>
```

That might do it . . .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery.blur()` function to remove the focus.

```
$('#box').focus();
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#box').blur();
}, 2000);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UX8G5/)

Comment: And what about the browser compatibility? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement#Browser_compatibility

Comment: not working...I tried adding a timeout as well, but the blur does not remove the cursor for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the html tag of the input as span

```
<span id="file_fake" class="radius_left">Browse</span>
```

And a little fix in the css

```
#file_fake { line-height: 33px; text-indent: 10px; }
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/36t3G/4/

Comment: I write to the `.value` property in JavaScript...can't do this with a span...but otherwise a good idea.